# How do I make an HTML iframe form target be another iframe

Tags: html

My website has an `iframe` with a form inside it. What I need is that when the form gets submitted, its target is another `iframe`, on the parent page. So my setup is basically this:

```
<div>
    <iframe name="iframe1"></iframe>
    <iframe name="iframe2"></iframe>
</div>
```

So i'm looking for something like this: `<form action="processor.php" target="parent:iframe2">`

I am not sure how to do this, help will be much appriciated :). Thank you!

Comment: try `target="iframe2"` where iframe2 is the name of the other iframe

Comment: another question is: "Why iframes" ?

Comment: you can just redirect to the send iframe's url  from the php file itseld using header("Location : http://target-url");

Comment: @mplungjan Thank you, it works! I'm quite confused as to why it does, though...

Comment: It is a named window so it should work the same as if you had a named popup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the iFrame has a name, it is a named window and you can target it by name:

```
target="iframe2"
```